# Enabling SSH compression in Sourcetree Windows for a mercurial repository

Tags: ssh, mercurial, compression, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am on  Windows 7 - Sourcetree 1.4.1.0 - Embedded Mercurial 2.6.1

Target is a private mercurial repo hosted on bitbucket.

How do I enable SSH compression so that my transactions are faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick Google search yielded [this document](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=271943168#ConfiguremultipleSSHidentitiesforGitBash,MacOSX,&Linux-ConfigurecompressionforMercurial):

> Edit the Mercurial global configuration file (~/.hgrc). Add the following line to the UI section:
>
> `ssh = ssh -C`
>
> When you are done the file should look similar to the following:
>
> `[ui]`
> `# Name data to appear in commits`
> `username = Mary Anthony <manthony@atlassian.com>`
> `ssh = ssh -C`

On Windows, the Mercurial settings file is located here:

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\hg_local\Mercurial.ini
```

The contents of the file are actually not to be changed, as its header explains:

> ```
> ; System-wide Mercurial config file.
> ;
> ; !!!  Do Not Edit This File !!!
> ;
> ; This file will be replaced by the installer on every upgrade.
> ; Editing this file can cause strange side effects on Vista.
> ;
> ; http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/issue/135
> ;
> ; To change settings you see in this file, override (or enable) them in
> ; your user Mercurial.ini file, where USERNAME is your Windows user name:
> ;
> ; XP or older    - C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Mercurial.ini
> ; Vista or later - C:\Users\USERNAME\Mercurial.ini
> ```

I don't have a Mac, so I can't test this, but [this Atlassian answer](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/138977/location-of-embedded-sourcetree-mercurial) states that the location of this file for Mac is:

```
/Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/mercurial_local/hg_local/
```

Comment: I already went through all those docs on their site and the problem is about finding the .hgrc file because, I use embedded mercurial and don't know whether it actually stores that file on the disk, if it does, no idea where its location could be.

Comment: Can we just copy the ssh = ssh -C line to the ini file as explained in that header? I can't test now as I'm on a Mac and this was posted a while ago. If you could test it, it would be helpful for others too. Atlassian should probably include this in their docs. Great find!

Comment: This link helped (applies to Mac, btw): https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/138977/location-of-embedded-sourcetree-mercurial
Then I looked around in `Program Files (x86)/Atlassian`, didn't find it; looked around in `AppData`, found it :)

Comment: Very cool find. Thanks for that extra link. It seems like the most logical equivalent to search on the Windows machine

Comment: Doesn't allow to me to award bounty, but it should happen in 24 hours.

Comment: It seems that the Windows setup file is located here:  `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Atlassian\SourceTree\hgrc_sourcetree`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm using TortoiseHg, but the concept should be the same.

Here is my original `c:\somerepo\.hg\hgrc` file:

```
[paths]
default = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/someuser/somerepo
```

So what's happening with `ssh`?  Let's debug a pull statement, `hg pull --debug` on the command-line.  I noticed it is running `C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib\TortoisePlink.exe` instead of `ssh` to make the call:

```
PS C:\somerepo> hg pull --debug
pulling from ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/someuser/somerepo
running "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib\TortoisePlink.exe" -ssh -2 hg@bitbucket.org "hg -R someuser/somerepo serve --stdio"
sending hello command
sending between command
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

So let's just reuse the call, add compression (yay!), non-interactive (batch) and our key:

```
[paths]
default = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/someuser/somerepo

[ui]
ssh = "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib\TortoisePlink.exe" -ssh -2 -C -batch -i "c:\keys\somekey.ppk"
```